# Google not indexing pages using php variables

Tags: seo, google, php, search-engine-indexing

For example google isnt indexing this page.

https://yorkes.live/beach.php?location=flahertys

however does index;

https://yorkes.live/privacy-policy-yorkes.pdf

I have a sitemap.xml up and working.

This content has been up for months. I thought it would have indexed by now.

here is a snippet of sitemap.

```
<url>
  <loc>https://yorkes.live/beach.php?location=flahertys</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-10-01T12:59:19+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

I have no robots.txt

Comment: There is no guarantee that Google will index every page.  Have you looked at the Search Console.  It tells you what pages are indexed and why others have not.  Sure, the reason is not detailed, but its a start.

Comment: 'Discovered - currently not indexed' is the only indicator.

Comment: PHP variables have nothing to do with it, you have more pages than Google is willing to index.  Your site is pretty new, it doesn't have much reputation (external links,) and you may not link to your deep pages from other pages well.

Comment: Since you mentioned sitemaps, you should also read [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).  Sitemaps have almost no SEO benefits.  A sitemap can help Googlebot discover content, but URLs need links before Google decides to index them.  Sitemaps don't usually help with indexing and don't help with rankings.